# http call to server works in browser, but in android returns response code 500 and file not found error

Tags: java, android, jsp, http

I was wondering if someone could help put me on the right track for debugging. I have an android device that is making an http call to a server, which is suppose to return a string response to the android device. When I make the http call in the browser, it is working. When I make it in my android app it returns "file not found exception".

When get the Response code, on Android device, from the server it is returning 500 (internal server error), but again, **my http call works in the browser**.

My server is receiving http request in a jsp page, which converts into servlet and and then tomcat server works (translate into java class and machine code) and then generate the resultant HTML code, then send it back to browser.

I am very new to servers so I don't know how to debug what is going on in my server that could cause an error for android when everything works in browser.

**What are the possible problems that could be causing this and how can I start to debug?**

Here is my code for making the http call in Android, which is running on a separate thread:

```
URL url = new URL(uri);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Expect", "100-continue");
urlConnection.connect();

int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode(); //can call this instead of con.connect()
if (responseCode >= 500 && responseCode <= 599) {

    throw new Exception("Response Code from Server: " + responseCode); 

   }

else {

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    result = "";
    String inLine;


    while ((inLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        result += inLine;
    }

    in.close();

    Log.d("MainActivity", "IP Address is: " + result);

    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about where you see "file not found exception" ? Is that a server exception, resulting in a 500 error on the client side? If it's the case, then you know what the problem is: the app requested a file name that does not exist and that makes the server crashing. Fix the server to handle this with 404 error and make sure you pass the proper file name in the client.

Comment: @BladeCoder Yes, the file not found exception is thrown in my android log cat, but the file that cannot be found is a file that connects to the servlet on the server. I will look into this...

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to connect with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

That is good to use in browsers (desktop), but for mobile applications you have to use `10.0.2.2` instead.

It worth to say that you can use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) and perform an HTTP request with a few lines.

Comment: You'd get a timeout exception trying to connect to localhost, not a 500

Answer (score 0):

Try removing these 2 lines:

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Expect", "100-continue");
```

It's invalid to use these if you are not sending a request body at the same time. You just want to perform a simple GET request.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work when I remove these two lines. I still get the same 500 response code from server.

Comment: 5xx error means an error on the server side (4xx is on the client side). Check the server logs to know what went wrong. Maybe the server expects some headers to be set, or you are calling a specific URL which causes the server to run into a bug.

Comment: Also: in the URL, make sure you properly URLEncode all the parameters which may contain non URL-valid characters with URLEncoder.